# Stability of neutron

Tags: particle-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come neutrons in a nucleus don't decay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9098/how-come-neutrons-in-a-nucleus-dont-decay)

It is known that free neutron decays in 15 minutes on average. Why is it much more stable when "placed" in nuclei?

Edit: I see that this question had been asked already ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9098/how-come-neutrons-in-a-nucleus-dont-decay)) and can be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Neutron decay produces a proton. Free neutron decays since this leads to a lower energy state. However, if this happens in a nucleus then due to the already existing positive charge of all the other protons, it will result in a higher energy state. In fact, the opposite may happen if a nucleus has an excess of protons: some of them may transform into neutrons. See [beta decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) for more on both transformations. On average the heavier the nucleus the higher the stable ratio of neutrons to protons.

Comment: Speaking classically, is this a dynamic equilibrium i.e. are neutrons decaying into protons but this is balanced by protons decaying into neutrons? Or I'd guess from a QM perspective, I'm asking are the neutrons and protons mixed in the nucleus?

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Does it mean that $\beta^{-}$ decay leads to nuclei with higher energy state? Perpetuum mobile?

Comment: @JohnRennie I doubt it.. Proton's don't decay: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay . More accurately, they haven't been observed to. Many experiments have been set up to find out if they decay, but they haven't found anything, pushing half-life estimates to $10^{(\text{I think 37)}} y$. Proton decay is predicted by many of the new theories, though.

Comment: @Manishearth Protons don't decay, but they may transform into neutrons in [β+ decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#.CE.B2.2B_decay). This happens in isotops with too many protons (compared to stable isotopes), e.g. C11, O15, K40.

Comment: @MurodAbdukhakimov Both types of β decay occur when the final configuration has lower energy. β- occurs in the nuclei with too many neutrons (most famous one probably being C14 which transforms via β- into N14). β+ occurs in the nuclei with too many protons (see examples in the previous comment).